# why i'm not able to register service-worker.js on localhost?

Tags: vue.js, localhost, service-worker

When I try to build a VueJs app on development mode, it broke the service-worker.js file.

I build with:

```
npm run build-dev
```

settings:

```
"build-dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development",
```

and I register with:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
  ready() {
    console.log('App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n' + 'For more details, visit ...');
  },
  registered() {
    console.log('Service worker has been registered.');
  },
  cached() {
    console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.');
  },
  updatefound() {
    console.log('New content is downloading.');
  },
  updated() {
    console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
  },
  offline() {
    console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.');
  },
  error(error) {
    console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
  }
})
```

but when load the page, it also call `http://localhost:5000/service-worker.js` (which doesn't in prod mode, with `vue-cli-service build`; there, it seems it include in generic "compiled" script). Of course, it doesn't find it, since its on /script/service-worker.js path. But I want it compile as for prod, with compiled .js.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue can be with the http client you are using.By default it might be taking localhost to locate the file *'service-worker.js'* in your case. So you can use :

## devServer.proxy

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: '${baseUrl}'
  }
}
```

For more reference : https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver-proxy

Answer (score 0):

I think because service workers needs SSL, try adding some kind of fake ssl over your local host.

Comment: SSL is not needed in .localhost with chrome and all browsers with localhost names like 127.0.0.1